# (AngularJS) Changing the year range of ngbDatepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

For users to input their birthdays, I utilized ngbDatepicker for that

```
   <div class="input-group">
      <input id="field_dateOfBirth" type="text" class="form-control" name="dateOfBirth" ngbDatepicker #dateOfBirthDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="staff.dateOfBirth" required  />
       <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dateOfBirthDp.toggle()">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </button>                     
       </span>                      
   </div>
```

When I clicked on the calendar icon, everything is fine until I realized that the year range is only up till 10 years. (2017-2007)

I've tried searching for documentations on this, but I have no idea how to change the date range. (using typescript)

Comment: It's right there, in the API documentation: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api: *minDate: Min date for the navigation. If not provided will be 10 years before today or `startDate`*

Comment: Oh man, no idea why I couldn't search for it. Thank you.